# Merge with an apostroph as first character

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I have a script that imports from a flat file data and merge them. I have around 190'000 rows of data daily to merge.

It takes me around 30 minutes. Now it takes me more than 2 hours. A new person who joined the company with the name

```
't Hart
```

as given name caused the trouble

The error is like this

> Code: 0xC0202092
>   Source: Data Flow Task 1 Source - zuko_GLDAP_DUMP_csv [1]
>   Description: An error occurred while processing file "D:...\NameOfTheFlatFile.csv" on
>
> data row 82396.  End Error  Error: 2014-02-12 05:00:41.61
>   Code: 0xC0047038     Source: Data Flow Task 1 SSIS.
>
> Pipeline
>
> Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "Source - zuko_GLDAP_DUMP_csv" (1) returned error code 0xC0202092.
>   The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput().
>
> The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.
>
> There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  05:00:01  Finished: 05:00:42  Elapsed:  40.235 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed

So I went into the file and saw the name (`'t Hart`).

I do this (not the whole code)

```
MERGE person AS TARGET
USING temp_person AS SOURCE
ON (TARGET.per_pid = SOURCE.per_pid)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET 
    TARGET.[per_name] = SOURCE.[per_name]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (
        [per_name]
    )
    VALUES( 
        SOURCE.[per_name]
    );
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

This has a clue to it sql injection is the only way to tackle the scenario btw.

```
USE [adventureworks2008]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[name](
        [name] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,

) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

select * from name

insert into name values ('James ''t Hart ')

SELECT REPLACE(name , '''', '''''') from name
```